# Is there any way to plus multi array number in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array. With each item in array is an array number. And the length of each array is the same. For example:

```
var data = [[1,2,4,1], [2,2,1,3], [1,1,2,2], ...]
```

And the result I want to have:

```
=> res = [4, 5, 7, 6]
```

`res` is the result of adding arrays according to the corresponding index. And of course my `data` may also contain lots of items.
I have referenced through the `lodash.unzipWith`. But it doesn't seem viable. With any advice. please let me know. Sorry for my weak English

Comment: Yes, [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and write something like this, without lodash or anything

```js
const data = [[1,2,4,1], [2,2,1,3], [1,1,2,2]]

const sumArrs = (arrs) => {
  return arrs.reduce((prev, curr) => {
    return curr.map((num, i) => num + (prev[i] || 0))
  }, [])
}

console.log(sumArrs(data))
```